# What are the limits on the area affected by an Alarm spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

I am fairly new to D&D, and I am trying to figure out the line between using spells creatively and abusing the spell. With regard to the [*alarm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm) spell, the text reads:

> Choose door, a window, or an area within range that is no larger than a 20-foot cube.

How I read this is that you can designate any contiguous area within the spell's range with a total volume less than that of a cube with a side length of 20 ft., so 20 ^ 3 = 8,000 ft.

It so happens that the volume of a 30ft hollow hemisphere with 1ft thick sides is 8,060.83 cubic feet *(I used [this "Volume of a partial sphere Calculator"](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223382199) to find the area of a partial sphere with a radius of 29ft and a height of 28ft and subtracted that from the volume of a 30 ft radius sphere)*. That can be easily made to equal 8,000 cubic feet with only minor adjustments.

Is this use of *alarm* allowed according to a strict interpretation of the rules and do you think would it be acceptable to use in game play?

Comment: So basically, you are proposing to ward an arbitrarily large area by only warding an arbitrarily thin line along its perimeter?

Comment: Related: [Does “no larger than” imply shapability?](/questions/112756)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you state, the text of [*alarm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm) says:

> You set an alarm against unwanted intrusion. Choose a door, a window, or an area within range that is no larger than a 20-foot cube.

The spell allows you a 20 foot cube of space, or smaller. ["Cube"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Cube) is a spell area descriptor which states:

> You select a cube's point of origin, which lies anywhere on a face of the cubic effect. The cube's size is expressed as the length of each side.
>
> A cube's point of origin is not included in the cube's area of effect, unless you decide otherwise.

Now the debate of whether or not your cylinder is "larger" than a 20-foot cube. I would argue it is; despite the fact you could make the volume less than that of the cube, your area does not fit *inside* the designated space. The other reason I argue in favour of this interpretation is that because of how math works, under your interpretation you could theoretically make *alarm* cover a half-mile radius and be notified whenever something enters that area. That is clearly out of the scope of a first-level spell.